# Is this windshield crack definitely caused by impact?

Tags: windshield

I have a windshield crack on a new vehicle that I originally thought was a stress crack, since it appears to originate at the edge and move toward the center, and I did not ever notice any impacts occur. However, when looking closely I see at one point in the "fault line" a pattern that could maybe be argued is an impact site. I guess the real question is: could something like this develop in the middle of a stress crack, or does the existence of this pattern mean it is undeniably an impact crack? I realize photos can only convey so much, so hopefully they are helpful. I took [two photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfW4n.jpg), in the first one the windshield is still dirty, but I think the crack is focused better there. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot tell you with 100% surety this was caused by an impact, but **I'd suggest it probably was**. Glass is a strange beast. It does have some flexibility to it, but if you get a stress riser in it, a crack can form. A rock impact creates a *HUGE* stress riser in the glass and the crack runs from there.

If you'd like to know more about stress risers, you can read [this Q&A I wrote](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/18184/4152).